# How to specify the type of a unittest.mock.sentinel?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I am using `unittest.mock.sentinel` to provide dumb values to my test functions and then assert calls.

I'd like to be able to specify the type of the sentinel so that it passes type checking in the methods.

MWE:

```
import collections
from unittest.mock import sentinel

def fun(x):
    if not isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
        raise TypeError('x should be iterable')
    pass

def test_fun_pass_if_x_is_instance_iterable():
# this does not work and raise because sentinel is not iterable
    assert fun(sentinel.x) is None
```

## EDIT

I have tried to do `sentinel.x = collections.Iterable()` but got the error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Iterable with abstract methods __iter__
```

So far I can do `sentinel.x = tuple()` or `sentinel.x = list()` for instance, but these are special case of an iterable

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that `collections.Iterable` is an abstract base class (ABC) and cannot be instantiated directly. That's what the error message says, the method `__iter__` is abstract, without body. You have to use a derived class or write one on your own.